# How to link Folly in CLion on Mac OS

Tags: macos, cmake, clion, folly

I installed [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly) by attempting both ways of installation.

```
brew install folly
./build/bootstrap-osx-homebrew.sh
```

I have verified that it's installed correctly at the location `/usr/local/Cellar/folly/2017.10.23.00`.

Now I'm trying to use it in a HelloWorld project in `CLion`. Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(HelloWorld)
message(STATUS "start running cmake....")
set(folly_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/folly/2017.10.23.00)
find_package(Boost 1.66)
find_package(folly 2017.10.23.00)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")

    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

if(folly_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "folly_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${folly_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "folly_LIBRARIES: ${folly_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "folly_VERSION: ${folly_VERSION}")

    include_directories(${folly_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(HelloWorld ${SOURCE_FILES})

if(Boost_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
if(folly_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${folly_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

The error I get is:

```
  By not providing "Findfolly.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "folly", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "folly" (requested
  version 2017.10.23.00) with any of the following names:

    follyConfig.cmake
    folly-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "folly" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "folly_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "folly"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I'm setting `folly_DIR` right at the top but it's still unable to find. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that Boost 1.66 is currently not fully supported by CMake. A [fix is available in CMake master](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake), but you will have to patch your local installation.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase

> or set "*_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.

in the CMake error message should be treated as setting the **cached** variable to appropriate value.

Normally, the variable is set via command-line option `-D` when execute `cmake`. If you want to set the variable in `CMakeLists.txt`, add *CACHE* option to the set command:

```
set(folly_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/folly/2017.10.23.00 CACHE PATH "")
```

Make sure that given path contain one of the config files noted in the error message.

Comment: I think that's the other issue. I can't seem to locate those files anywhere on my system. https://github.com/facebook/folly/tree/master/CMake includes `folly-config.h.cmake` but not `folly-config.cmake`.

Comment: According to fully's `CMakeLists.txt`, the config file is installed into `share/folly`. Probably, `dev` package should contain that file.

Answer (score 0):

Create you own FindFolly.cmake file as following ([reference here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/iterlib/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindFolly.cmake)):

```
# Usage of this module as follows:
#
#     find_package(Folly)
#
# Variables used by this module, they can change the default behaviour and need
# to be set before calling find_package:
#
#  FOLLY_ROOT_DIR Set this variable to the root installation of
#                    folly if the module has problems finding
#                    the proper installation path.
#
# Variables defined by this module:
#
#  FOLLY_FOUND             System has folly libs/headers
#  FOLLY_LIBRARIES         The folly library/libraries
#  FOLLY_INCLUDE_DIR       The location of folly headers

find_path(FOLLY_ROOT_DIR
   NAMES include/folly/folly-config.h
)

find_library(FOLLY_LIBRARIES
   NAMES folly
   HINTS ${FOLLY_ROOT_DIR}/lib
)

find_library(FOLLY_BENCHMARK_LIBRARIES
   NAMES follybenchmark
   HINTS ${FOLLY_ROOT_DIR}/lib
)

find_path(FOLLY_INCLUDE_DIR
   NAMES folly/folly-config.h
   HINTS ${FOLLY_ROOT_DIR}/include
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
   find_package_handle_standard_args(Folly DEFAULT_MSG
   FOLLY_LIBRARIES
   FOLLY_INCLUDE_DIR
)

mark_as_advanced(
   FOLLY_ROOT_DIR
   FOLLY_LIBRARIES
   FOLLY_BENCHMARK_LIBRARIES
   FOLLY_INCLUDE_DIR
)
```

Then, you need to put this file into your CMake module path ([more detailes here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Using_external_libraries_that_CMake_doesn.27t_yet_have_modules_for)), that means:

1. Create a folder named "cmake/Modules/" under your project root
2. Put the FindFolly.cmake file in the created folder
3. Add the following line to your cmake file:

`set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")`